# PHP equivelant of Perl line?

Tags: php, perl

Can someone tell me if I'm right with this? I'm trying to port a fairly massive
perl script into OO-PHP, and have been stuck on a few things, this is one of them
and just need some confirmation if I'm doing it right, the perl code is:

```
my ($command,@args)=split(/\n/,$message);
```

is this the same as doing this in PHP?

```
list($command, $args[]) = preg_split('/\n/', $message);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. What you're trying to do is invalid and will not work. The equivalent PHP code would be:

```
$args = preg_split('/\n/', $message);
$command = array_shift($args);
```

The use of `preg_` functions should be only used when necessary, so you could actually replace the `preg_split` with:

```
explode("\n", $message);
```